# creating connection to online database via pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to test the connection between my work in the ftp and the database in db4free.net but i always get a time out error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException'
with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out'
```

here's my test.php

```
<?php
    $user = "user***";
    $pass = "***";
    $host = "www.db4free.net"; 
    $dbname = data123z; 
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $user, $pass);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT nom FROM aa";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row["nom"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

I tried even inserting the port 3306 and the IP address 85.10.205.173 but its all the same.

Comment: Can you telnet into the client from command line? `telnet 85.10.205.173 3306`

Comment: `C:\Windows\system32>telnet 85.10.205.173 3306
J
 5.6.24☺ⁿMEdI}];JD!☻Ç§Wf|^Agd@PT3Bmysql_native_password

Connection to host lost.`

Comment: Seems like you input the wrong password, then. Either that, or the host has too many connections and timed you out. Have you considered just setting up a local development environment with a tool such as [Vagrant](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/why-vagrant/index.html)

Comment: in local its all work fine but i want deploy my project via filezilla so i must have an online DB

Comment: That is not a suitable site to use for an online database in production. Their site explicitly states this. They may even be identifying this and dropping your connection as such. You can get a VPS for $5 through digitalocean. Please don't use db4free.net.